# How save and load checkbox with Alamofire

Tags: swift

When click checkbox for give like the checkbox is using and post to server like but after close project the checkbox is close but like in server exists and I want save checkbox all time exists

```
func didlikeAddlaterDesigner(_ sender: UIButton) {
    collectionPostion = array33[sender.tag].accountId!
    index = collectionPostion
     if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        like(userId:  LoginUser.accountId!, designerid: index!, like: false)
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
        like(userId:  LoginUser.accountId!, designerid: index!, like: true)
    }
}
func like(userId : Int, designerid : Int, like : Bool ) {
    let parameters: Parameters = ["userid" : userId, "designerid" : designerid ,"mylike" : like]
    AF.request(URL_like, method: .post , parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let data : JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
                let result = response.result.value
                return
            case .failure:
                print(response.error)
                print("fail")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the server has to save that the user has checked that box and should return a flag with the response that indicates the state of the checkbox.

Or, You can save that flag yourself to the UserDefaults.

```
func didlikeAddlaterDesigner(_ sender: UIButton) {
    collectionPostion = array33[sender.tag].accountId!
    index = collectionPostion
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "CheckBoxState_\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        like(userId:  LoginUser.accountId!, designerid: index!, like: false)
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "CheckBoxState_\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        like(userId:  LoginUser.accountId!, designerid: index!, like: true)
    }
}
```

Then when loading the view, just set the value of the checkbox from the UserDefaults

```
checkBox.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "CheckBoxState_\(index)")
```

But please note that using the second way will cause the flag to be reset when the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: It did not work with me probably because it is not core data

Comment: try calling UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() after setting the flag